# Need help solving complex numbers task

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to solve the following task:
$$
(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2})^{24}
$$

What should I do first? Should I rewrite it like
$$
(\frac{2-\sqrt{3}+i}{2})^{24}
$$
and then transform it to the form $r(\cos{\phi}+i\sin{\phi})$? Well, it actually didn't help me a lot as $r=2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Your $r$ is off by factor of $2$; I think that you forgot to take into account the denominator of $2$ in the original. Note that while $r$ isn’t very nice, $r^2$ is quite simple.

Comment: Remarkably, the result is real, being equal to $(-1351 + 780 \sqrt 3)^2 = 3650401 - 2107560 \sqrt 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's convert to polar form, give up halfway, and have it somehow turn out alright.
$$ z = 1 - \frac{\sqrt 3 - i}{2} = \frac{2 - \sqrt 3 + i}{2} $$
$$ r^2 = \left( \frac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{2} \right)^2 + (1/2)^2 = \frac{4 - 4 \sqrt{3} + 3 + 1}{4} = 2 - \sqrt{3} $$
$$ r = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 2}{2} $$

Finding $\theta$ is hard. Let's not do it. Instead, consider $z/r$.
$$ \frac{z}{r} = \frac{2 - \sqrt 3 + i}{\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 2} = \frac{2 - \sqrt 3 + i}{\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 2} \frac{\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2}{\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2} = \frac{(2 - \sqrt 3 + i)(\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2)}{4} $$

This numerator looks complicated. Let's pull out the $\sqrt 2$ and focus on the rest:
$$ (2 - \sqrt 3 + i)(\sqrt 3 + 1) = 2 \sqrt 3 + 2 - 3 - \sqrt 3 + i \sqrt 3 + i = \sqrt 3 - 1 + i \sqrt 3 + i = (\sqrt 3 + i)(1 + i) $$

So we now have some terms that may look familiar:
$$ \frac{z}{r} = \frac{(\sqrt 3 + i)(1 + i) \sqrt 2}{4} = \frac{\sqrt 3 + i}{2} \frac{1 + i}{\sqrt 2} $$

These are a sixth and eighth root of unity, respectively. So raising them to the $24$th kills them entirely!
$$ z^{24} = r^{24} (z/r)^{24} = r^{24} = (2 - \sqrt 3)^{12} $$

After this, you just have to bash it out.

Answer (score 2):

Letting

$$x = 1 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 + \frac {\Bbb i} 2$$

we have

$$x - 1 - \frac {\Bbb i} 2 = - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 ,$$

whence by squaring, rearranging terms and separating real in the left from imaginary in the right, we get

$$x^2 - 2x = \Bbb i (x-1) ,$$

whence by squaring one last time we get

$$x^4 - 4x^3 + 5x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 .$$

(In algebraic field theory the polynomial $P = X^4 - 4X^3 + 5X^2 - 2X + 1 = 0$ is called "the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\Bbb Q$". Notice that $P(x) = 0$.)

Having obtained this, notice that we may divide the polynomial $X^{24}$ by $P$ and obtain a quotient $Q$ and a remainder $R$, with the degree of the remainder $\le 3$ (because the degree of $P$ is $4$):

$$X^{24} = P Q + R .$$

If we evaluate this equality in $x$, we get that

$$x^{24} = \underbrace{P(x)} _{=0} Q(x) + R(x) = R(x) .$$

In principle, then, you just have to perform that division, obtain $R$ and evaluate $R$ in $x$.

---

Unfortunately, because of that large power $24$, this process can be quite tedious. Let us devise an easier strategy in order to work with smaller numbers. The trick is to notice that $X^{24} = (X^6)^4$, so perform first the division of $X^6$ by $P$ (which is very easy), and get

$$X^6 = (X^2 + 4X + 11) P(X) + 26X^3 - 48X^2 + 18X -11 ,$$

whence by evaluating in $x$ you get

$$x^6 = (x^2 + 4x + 11) \underbrace{P(x)} _{=0} + 26x^3 - 48x^2 + 18x -11 = 26 \Bbb i - 15 \Bbb i \sqrt 3$$

(you'll have to evaluate this, but fortunately the numbers involved are small).

Finally, then,

$$x^{24} = (x^6)^4 = (26 \Bbb i - 15 \Bbb i \sqrt 3)^4 = (26 - 15 \sqrt 3)^4 = (1351 - 780 \sqrt 3)^2 = 3650401 - 2107560 \sqrt 3 .$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you rewrite the number to polar form, i.e. $re^{i\theta}$, you can easily take the $n$th power of that number, as $\left(re^{i\theta}\right)^n=r^ne^{in\theta}$.

Comment: I haven't done the calculation, but I believe that your $\theta$ will be quite ugly (i.e. the arctangent of an ugly number).

Comment: @AlexM. Yeah, you're probably right - looking for alternative methods now.

Comment: Well, one night's good sleep can do miracles. See my answer.

Comment: @AlexM. Very nice! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Generalize the problem, when $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\text{n}\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\text{z}^\text{n}=\left(\Re[\text{z}]+\Im[\text{z}]i\right)^\text{n}=\left(|\text{z}|e^{\left(\arg(\text{z})+2\pi k\right)i}\right)^\text{n}=|\text{z}|^\text{n}e^{\text{n}\left(\arg(\text{z})+2\pi k\right)i}$$

Where $|\text{z}|=\sqrt{\Re^2[\text{z}]+\Im^2[\text{z}]}$, $\arg(\text{z})$ is the complex argument of $\text{z}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

So, for your problem:

1. $$1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}+i}{2}$$
2. $$\left|1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right|=\frac{\left|2-\sqrt{3}+i\right|}{\left|2\right|}=\frac{\sqrt{\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)+1^2}}{2}=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$$
3. $$\arg\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right)=\arg\left(2-\sqrt{3}+i\right)-\arg\left(2\right)=$$
   $$\arg\left(2-\sqrt{3}+i\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{5\pi}{12}$$

Comment: How did you find that arctangent?

Comment: In that case, you could have used Wolfram Alpha to compute the original expression...

Comment: @AlexM. This problem seems like a competition problem, where trig functions of $\frac{n \pi}{12}$ are pretty commonplace. So maybe this is the "intended" approach? IDK though.

Comment: @HenrySwanson: After some reflection I have come up with a purely algebraic solution, which I (arogantly) believe to be *the* intended approach.